# How do I create a Singleton Serial Queue with GCD?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

This is what I am using (inside a class called Utils.swift)

```
static let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.wi-mobile.wmForms", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

However, it seems like I create a new queue everytime I call something like

```
dispatch_async(UtilsUI.serialQueue)
```

I would need it to be within another class as I can't instantiate a new queue every time I get into the ViewController I need it to run.

I need to dispatch some network calls, but I need the UI to return immediately after calling the first one, however I need all of them to run serially.

EDIT:

I am using callbacks, and maybe there's where my serialization fails, here's an example:

```
func sendFormToMiddleware() {

    successSending = false
    errorSending = false

    let seconds: String = String(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let tbvotos: TbvotosDB = TbvotosDB(survey_id: idForm, transaction_id: "\(WMConfiguration.getTranid())", lu_date: seconds , id_movil: WMConfiguration.getUser(), status: "1")

   dispatch_async(UtilsUI.serialQueue) {
        self.conectionHandler.doPostWmFormsService(self.attemptToSendForm, service: ConnectionHandler.Service.TBVOTOS, parameters: tbvotos.asArray()!)
    }
}

func attemptToSendForm(isOk: Bool, mData: [AnyObject], isLastEntity: Bool) -> Void {
    if isOk {
        successSending = true
        Queries.unifyTransactionIDForCurrentFormQuestions(idForm, tranId: WMConfiguration.getTranid())
        let responses = Queries.getResponses(idForm)

        dispatch_async(UtilsUI.serialQueue) {
            self.conectionHandler.insertRespuestas(self.callbackEnvioRespuestas, responses: responses)
        }

        self.removeAllOverlays()
        self.returnAfterSendingForm()
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        self.removeAllOverlays()
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        errorSending = true
        UtilsUI.showAlert(NSLocalizedString("Error al contactar con el Servidor", comment: "Fallo conexión middleware"), self)
    }
}
```

Here doPostWmFormsService's first parameter (attemptToSendForm) is the callback function. I can't figure what other approach should I use in case I am right.

Comment: Why do you think you're getting a new queue?  If I put your line of code in a class and then `print(UtilsUI.serialQueue)` twice, it shows me the same address both times (therefore same object).

Comment: I think I get a new queue because after watching the requests on the log, they don't run serially

Comment: Print the value that you're getting back from `serialQueue` to be sure.  It's possible (probable?) that your requests are being dispatched serially but that the networking itself isn't serialized.  Maybe update your question with an example of the code that you dispatch....

Comment: Looking at your edit, the question is, what does `doPostWmFormsService` do?  If it does anything asynchronous it would explain your situation.

Comment: It performs a POST request to my back-end

Comment: But does it do it synchronously within the queue where it's invoked?

Comment: I wrap every network operation with dispatch_async(UtilsUI.serialQueue) {} in order to attempt to make each wait for the previous one to complete before executing. Each 'cycle' has 6 operations and each is called through the callback of the previous, but when I call another cycle of operations, they don't wait until the previous 6 have finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question went out of scope in the comments, being it originally how to create a singleton queue in Swift, I must give credit to Phillip Mills as printing it twice `print(UtilsUI.serialQueue)` returns the same memory address, thus it is the same object and it's a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

It would need to be on a singleton to persist the same queue, you can use AppDelegate if its a 1 queue simple thing or make a dedicated singleton.

On your app Delegate:

```
static let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.wi-mobile.wmForms", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
```

Then to get it

```
  if let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
     dispatch_async(appDel.serialQueue)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to code it in swift, but from my objective c background I suggest you to use **dispatch_once**, something like creating a function where you init once your queue and then return it to the caller:

```
{
  var singleton:serialQueue 
  dispatch_once_t onceToken 
  dispatch_once(&onceToken,{ in singleton = ...

  return singleton;
}
```

then use the singleton

this will create one object and only one and return it each time u call the function...